# F#, Extracting grid coordinates from mouse cursor position relative to an IInputElement

Tags: f#

If I have a square grid (created in WPF/XAML) in any size, with a given number of cells per side, it should be ridiculously easy to calculate the coordinates to a cell that was clicked by getting the mouse cursor position relative to the grid element. As I try to learn F#, I experience some problems with the syntax and would appreciate some input.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
    // From a mouse event, fetch the position of the cursor relative to a IInputElement 
    let get_mouse_position (relative_to : IInputElement) (args : Input.MouseEventArgs) : (int*int) = 
        let position = args.GetPosition relative_to 
        ((Convert.ToInt32(position.X) / cellsPerSide), (Convert.ToInt32(position.Y) / cellsPerSide))

    // Get the position of the cursor relative to the grid 
    let get_cell_coordinates (element : IInputElement) =
        get_mouse_position element
```

However, when I try to use the coordinates retrieved by calling get_cell_coordinates somewhere else where (x,y) coordinates are needed, I get an error that says:

> This expression was expected to have type int * int but here has type 'a -> int * int

So, what am I doing wrong and why do I get this polymorph type and not just a tuple of integers?

Comment: You forgot to add the args in `get_mouse_position element`.  Get used to this error message; it will happen a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the static Mouse.GetPosition method to obtain the position of the mouse instead of Input.MouseEventArgs.

The code now looks as follows, if anyone else has the same problem:

```
    // From a mouse event, fetch the position of the cursor relative to a IInputElement 
let get_mouse_position (relative_to : IInputElement) : (int*int) = 
    let position = Mouse.GetPosition relative_to
    ((Convert.ToInt32(position.X) / cellsPerSide), (Convert.ToInt32(position.Y) / 32))

// Get the position of the cursor relative to the input element
let get_cell_coordinates (element : IInputElement) =
    get_mouse_position element
```

Answer (score 2):

The type you got is not a "polymorph" type, it's a function type. The reason you got a function of type `'a -> int * int` instead of the `int * int` result you were expecting is because you didn't pass all the parameters to your function, so F# returned a function that expected the rest of the parameters. This is called "partial application", and you can read more about it here:

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/

and

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/partial-application/

A quick summary of the two articles: in F#, all functions are treated as taking one parameter and returning one result. Yes, ALL functions. When you create a function that appears to take two parameters, F# rewrites it internally. It becomes a function that takes one parameter and returns a second function; this second function takes one parameter and returns the result. A concrete example will probably be useful at this point. Consider this function:

```
let doubleAndSubtract a b = (a * 2) - b
```

(Obviously, the parentheses around `a * 2` aren't actually needed, but I left them in to make the function unambiguous to read).

Internally, F# actually *rewrites* this function into the following:

```
let doubleAndSubtract a =
    let subtract b = (a * 2) - b
    subtract
```

In other words, it builds a function that "closes over" (captures) the value of `a` that you passed in. So the following two functions are completely equivalent:

```
let explicitSubtract b = (5 * 2) - b
let implicitSubtract = doubleAndSubtract 5
```

If you type these functions in to the F# interactive prompt and look at the types that it declares each function to have, `explicitSubtract` has type `b:int -> int`, and `implicitSubtract` has type `int -> int`. The only difference between these two is that the type of `explicitSubtract` names the parameter, whereas `implicitSubtract` doesn't "know" the name of its parameter. But both will take an int, and return an int (specifically, 10 minus the parameter).

Now, let's look at the type signature for `doubleAndSubtract`. If you typed it into the F# interactive prompt, you'll have seen that its type signature is `int -> int -> int`. In type signatures, `->` is right-associative, so that signature is really `int -> (int -> int)` -- in other words, a function that takes an int and returns a function that takes an int and returns an int. **But** you can also think of it as a function that takes two ints and returns an int, and you can define it that way.

So, what happened with your code here is that you defined the function like this:

```
let get_mouse_position (relative_to : IInputElement) (args : Input.MouseEventArgs) : (int*int) = ...
```

This is a function that takes two parameters (of types `IInputElement` and `Input.MouseEventArgs`) and returns a tuple of ints... **but** that's equivalent to a function that takes one parameter of type `IInputElement`, and returns a function that takes an `Input.MouseEventArgs` and returns a tuple of two ints. In other words, your function signature is:

```
IInputElement -> Input.MouseEventArgs -> (int * int)
```

When you called it as `get_mouse_position element` you passed it only a single parameter, so what you got was a function of type `Input.MouseEventArgs -> (int * int)`. The type checker reported this as type `'a -> int * int` (changing `Input.MouseEventArgs` into the generic type name `'a`) for reasons I don't want to get into here (this is already rather long), but that's why you got the result you got.

I hope this helps you understand F# functions better. And do read those two articles I linked to; they'll take your understanding another step further.

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailed answer, it's much clearer now!